# I am able to connect to my schema via Oracle SQL Developer but not via JDBC

Tags: oracle, ora-01034, ora-27101

I am trying to connect to a schema on Oracle 11g on remote server via JDBC and I am getting following error while I am able to successfully connect through Oracle SQL Developer. I used the same JDBC code to connect many others schema which was always successful.

```
Jun 20, 2018 11:29:21 AM util.DBConnect getConnection
INFO: Driver loaded
Jun 20, 2018 11:29:24 AM util.DBConnect getConnection
SEVERE: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Apparently your Oracle server is not started

Comment: I suspect you're confusing SID and service name, but without seeing exactly what you are using for both connections it's impossible to say what you are doing wrong.

Comment: @Manish you need to provide us connection string (host, port, service_name) you are using to connect OR make sure that the mentioned parameters are correctly providing during your connection.

Comment: my_connection_name.oracle.url = jdbc:oracle:thin:@dummyHostName.quintiles.net:1521/XYZ01
my_connection_name.oracle.driver = oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
my_connection_name.oracle.username = MY_USERNAME
my_connection_name.oracle.password = somepassword

Comment: this is a dummy valued properties of connection

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name my db is running and able to connect locally in server as well as remotely from Oracle Sql Developer tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding fully qualified sid name (XYZ01.abc.companydomain.com) in the url worked for me like following.

```
my_connection_name.oracle.url = jdbc:oracle:thin:@dummyHostName.companydomain.net:1521/XYZ01.abc.companydomain.com
```